# Change default border color of outline textfield

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the default border color of an outlined textfield from gray to a darker blue.

```
              <TextField
            variant={"outlined"}
            placeholder={t('landing_page.code.placeholder')}
            onChange={this.onCodeChanged}
            value={code}
            fullWidth={true}
            className={classes.codeInput}
            error={code ? code.length < 10 : false}
          />
```

This is the `codeInput`class:

```
  codeInput: {
     marginTop: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
```

I have tried overriding the color via theme, but it does not work:

```
  overrides: {
    MuiOutlinedInput: {
      root: {
        borderColor: "#2b303e"
      },
      notchedOutline: {
        borderRadius: "0",
        borderWidth: "2px",
        borderColor: "#2b303e"
      },
    },
  }
```

It is still gray as you can see in the image. 
I have identified the following css rules as the problem. With disabling this, everything looks fine. I just don't know how to do this

```
.MuiOutlinedInput-root-148 .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline-155 {
    border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Check this https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-ui-custom-outline-color?file=ValidField.js

Answer (score 0):

**Create a new css class for example:**

```
// app.css
.blueBorder {
}
```

**Add in the border you want and add `!important;` to overwrite.**

```
// app.css
.blueBorder{
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    border: 2px solid #2b303e!important;
}
```

**Assign it to your component:**

```
// js /  react component
<TextField
    variant={"outlined"}
    placeholder={t('landing_page.code.placeholder')}
    onChange={this.onCodeChanged}
    value={code}
    fullWidth={true}
    className={`blueBorder ${classes.codeInput}`}
/>
```

**Update to show error class**

```
// app.css
.blueBorder{
    border-radius: 0px!important;
    border: 2px solid #2b303e!important;
}
// Red border to denote error
.blueBorder-error {
   border-radius: 0px!important;
   border: 2px solid red!important;
}
```

**Use the error class in the components className**
`condition ? true : false`

```
// js / component

<TextField
    variant={"outlined"}
    placeholder={t('landing_page.code.placeholder')}
    onChange={this.onCodeChanged}
    value={code}
    fullWidth={true}
    className={code.length < 10 ? `blueBorder-error ${classes.codeInput}` : `blueBorder ${classes.codeInput}}
/>
```

Comment: I've treid overriding it with `!important` but I want to keep the color for `error` for example, so it gets red by itself. Using `!important` would make it always blue

Comment: Not if you add another class for error? how are you detecting the error? If you like i can update my code to show you how you could apply the class if in a error state?

Comment: @user2529173 as have i, check  my answer :-)